# POST Request with Swift

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I'm trying to send data over from my iOS app to a PHP script. I have Title, Description and City. I want it to always save every info I send to it from my iOS app and always make a new one every time I send it data. The problem I'm having is, when I go to the PHP file on my browser, nothing shows up. The title, description and city field is always blank. But in my Xcode console I see it returning everything correctly. Here's my swift code.

```
func postToServerFunction() {        
        var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://vittletest.netii.net/index.php")!
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "title=testing&description=hello&city=RanchoCordova"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            println("response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

And here's my PHP file.

```
<?php 
    $something = "Some Info";
    echo $something;

     $title = $_POST['title'];
     $description = $_POST['description'];
     $city = $_POST['city']; 

     echo "<br />";
     echo "Title: ". $title;  
     echo "<br />";
     echo "Description: ". $description; 
     echo "<br />";
     echo "City: ". $city;  
 ?>
```

And here's my console output on Xcode.

```
2015-01-03 10:05:50.861 VittleTest[616:28516] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9f5ae5e3f0> { URL: http://vittletest.netii.net/index.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 309;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sat, 03 Jan 2015 18:05:52 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.2.17";
} }
responseString = Optional(<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 Some Info<br />Title: testing<br />Description: hello<br />City: RanchoCordova 
 </body>
</html>
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
)
```

I hope I gave you guys enough info to help me out because I can't seem to figure it out since I'm not the best with PHP.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

If you view the script through the browser than thats differrent because it will be a separate browser request without post values.

If you want to persist data, you will need to find a way to store that data using a database or perhaps some files.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is ... From swift you are passing post params.

```
 let postString = "title=testing&description=hello&city=RanchoCordova"
```

But when you hit the url in the browser directly You are not posting those params. Thats why they are blank

Comment: How can I post and save the parameters?

Comment: Where do you want to save